# I want to install a pip package, but there's some error occurred

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to install a pip package, but pip said that my python version is 2.7, and I check my python version with `python --version`, and it said my version is 3.8.3, there is a deprecation:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
```

And there is an error occurred too:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dg/by5qxx0s3d369vfkbzbfslfh0000gn/T/pip-install-C65qdp/async-timeout/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dg/by5qxx0s3d369vfkbzbfslfh0000gn/T/pip-install-C65qdp/async-timeout/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/dg/by5qxx0s3d369vfkbzbfslfh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lxWs_X
         cwd: /private/var/folders/dg/by5qxx0s3d369vfkbzbfslfh0000gn/T/pip-install-C65qdp/async-timeout/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/dg/by5qxx0s3d369vfkbzbfslfh0000gn/T/pip-install-C65qdp/async-timeout/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pathlib
    ImportError: No module named pathlib
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help, thanks very much.

Comment: Your `python` is `3.x` but your `pip` is still `2.7`. Could be a broken symlink. Try `python -m pip install ...` or `pip3 install ...`.

Comment: Try using pip3.

Comment: use pip3 or redefine your pip alias to mean pip3